# Como marcar una ubicacion especifica en mi Maps con PHP-Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

tengo el siguiente codigo en la cual me muestra la zona de ubicacion que estoy especificando, pero se podra marcar con una imagen(.jpg) que quiera agregar el lugar que yo quiera. osea que me salga la imagen donde estoy poniendo la latitud y longitud?

este es el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title> INSERTAR MAPA EN GOOGLE MAPS</title>


 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"> </script>

 <script>

 function init(){
    var mapOption = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.06244,-77.12272),
     zoom: 15,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOption);

  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

 </script>


  </head>
  <body>

  <div id="map" style="width:1000px; height: 800px; border: solid; border-color: #00FFFF  "></div>


</body>
</html>﻿
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrega un [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) (marcador) a tu mapa:

```
// Define tu marcador (pon la url de tu imagen en la propiedad **icon**)
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: -12.06244, lng: -77.12272 }, // aca defines las coordenadas
    icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
});
// Agregar tu marcador al mapa
marker.setMap(map);
```

de acuerdo a tu código lo pondrías en:

```
function init(){
   var mapOption = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.06244,-77.12272), 
     zoom: 15,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOption);

   // Define tu marcador (pon la url de tu imagen en la propiedad **icon**)
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: -12.06244, lng: -77.12272 }, // aca defines las coordenadas
      icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
   });
   // Agregar tu marcador al mapa
   marker.setMap(map);
}
```

---

Editado:

Para mostrar 2 o mas marcadores:

```
function init(){
   var mapOption = {
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(-12.06244,-77.12272),
     zoom: 15,
     mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
   };
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOption);

   // Marcador 1
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: -12.06244, lng: -77.12272 }, // coodernadas del marcador 1
      icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
   });
   marker.setMap(map);

   // Marcador 2
   var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: -12.06444, lng: -77.12472 }, // coordenadas del marcador 2
      icon: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
   });
   marker2.setMap(map);
}
```

El resultado son 2 marcadores en el mapa [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: erick, añadi tu codigo y funciono excelente. pero tengo una consulta mas, como hago para que se pueda ver varios puntos, osea mostrar 2 a mas ubicaciones

Comment: Vuelve a añadir otro marker,  var marker2 = ..  ,   y de ahi marker2.setMap(map);

Comment: lo añadi pero solo me muestra lo ultimo, y no el primero... como haria?

Comment: mira mi respuesta editada, es para 2 marcadores

Comment: ayaa, yo estaba duplicando desde"var mapOptions..." . entonces si funciona normalmente. una consulta mas erick, y si en vez de añadir una imagen, añado un mensaje y una imagen a la vez... como lo haria?

Comment: agrega la propiedad **title** a cada marcador, así como estás agregando las propiedades position e icon  ->  **title: "My títuto"**, el título se mostrará cuando mantengas el cursor encima de tu marcador por 1 segundo.